# Signal and slot Qt not working

Tags: c++, qt

myslot is not being called. MyPage is a QWizardPage.

```
MyPage::initializePage()
{  
  connect(this,SIGNAL(mysignal), this,SLOT(myslot()));
  emit mysignal();
}


void ProgressPage::myslot(){
  cout<<"in ";
}
```

My header file contains the following signals and slots,

```
public slots:
  void myslot();

signals:
  void mysignal();
```

What am I missing? My debugger executes till emit, but is not able to go the slot.

Comment: `connect` returns `true` if the connection succeeds; otherwise returns `false`. So, first of all, try to check if connection was successful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct `connect` should read:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(mysignal()), this, SLOT(myslot()));
```

You're missing the parentheses in the signal's signature. Also the `this` receiver is implied in the non-static `connect` and can be omitted. The `connect` that you invoke is a static method.

Comment: In Qt5, one can use pointer to member function instead of the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros so that such errors would be caught at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your class with signals and slots uses the `Q_OBJECT` macro:

```
class MyPage {
    Q_OBJECT

    //...
}
```

and run qmake again.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the "()" after the "mysignal" Signal.